# Using pandas how can i find a string from every row in a excel A in another excel B(from all columns) and if it matches, return column from B

Tags: python, pandas

I have two excel. Excel A and Excel B.

Excel A has 2 columns. Excel B has 5 columns

I want to find value each from Column2 in A in All 5 columns of Excel B(it may not be exact match, its just may just contain that vaule)

Example
Excel A

| Column A1 | Column A2 |
| --- | --- |
| 405 | 121h |
| 496 | 156b |
| 456 | 325v |

ExcelB

| Column B1 | Column B2 | Column B3 | Column B4 | Column B5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121h*12 | Cell 2 | Cell1 | abc | def |
| Cell 3 | **156b**456 | Cell2 | efg | ijk |

Expecting Output

| Column A1 | Column A2 | ColumnB4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 405 | 121h | abc |
| 496 | 156b | efg |
| 456 | 325v |  |

Comment: When you ask a question on stackoverflow, you're supposed to "Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen." You currently give a problem, and expect others to solve it for you. This is not what stackoverflow is meant for.

Comment: sorry not able to gett anything.

I tried with nested for loop

ExcelB['MergedColumn'] = ExcelB[ExcelB.columns[:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)

for x in ExcelA["A2"]:
    for y,z in zip(ExcelB["MergedColumn"],ExcelB["B4"]):
        if (y.__contains__(x)):
            print(z)
            ExcelA['B4']=ExcelA["B4"].append(z)
    
ExcelA.head()

i get this error
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ExcelA` and `ExcelB` are DataFrames.

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a pattern made from ExcelA to use as a key for the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import re

to_merge = ['Column B4'] # use here all columns to merge

tmp = ExcelB.melt(to_merge)
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, ExcelA['Column A2']))
# '121h|156b|325v'

out = ExcelA.merge(tmp[to_merge], how='left', left_on='Column A2',
                   right_on=tmp['value'].str.extract(f'({pattern})',
                                                     expand=False))
```

Output:

```
   Column A1 Column A2 Column B4
0        405      121h       abc
1        496      156b       efg
2        456      325v       NaN
```

Comment: sorry not able to gett anything.

I tried with nested for loop

ExcelB['MergedColumn'] = ExcelB[ExcelB.columns[:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)

for x in ExcelA["A2"]:
    for y,z in zip(ExcelB["MergedColumn"],ExcelB["B4"]):
        if (y.__contains__(x)):
            print(z)
            ExcelA['B4']=ExcelA["B4"].append(z)
    
ExcelA.head()

i get this error
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Have you tried **my** approach?

Comment: Hi Yes, It gave me error saying

KeyError: "The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: [.....]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce this error? Have you changed anything in my answer and tested on the provided example?

Comment: havent change anything.Just changed field name.
You below step. Does this mean to just merge column names? or all columns with values from Excel B?
to_merge = ['Column B4'] # use here all columns to merge